# Cast Generic<Derived> to Generic<Base>

Tags: c#, oop, casting, covariance

I have a base WPF UserControl that handles some common functionality for derived UserControls. In the code-behind of any derived UserControl I call an event

```
private void SomeClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    HandleClick(sender);
    MyDataGrid.Items.Refresh();
}
```

In my base UserControl I do

```
public class BaseUserControl : UserControl {
   protected void HandleClick(object sender) {
       var vm = (BaseViewModel<Part>)DataContext;
       ...
   }
}
```

This throws an **InvalidCastException** since `DataContext` is of type `BaseViewModel` but of a derived type like `BaseViewModel<Wire>` or `BaseViewModel<Connector>`.

How can I cast that?

Comment: What does your generic class look like and what is T declared as? Related: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You can't - a `BaseViewModel<Wire>` simply *isn't* a `BaseViewModel<Part>`. Assuming `BaseViewModel<T>` is a class, you can't make this work. If it were an interface, you could use covariance.

Comment: Just because `A` and `B` have a particular inheritance relationship does *not* imply that `G<A>` and `G<B>` have the *same* inheritance relationship.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You cannot cast a `Generic<Derived>` to a `Generic<Base>`.

Just imagine if you could. You have a `List<Wolf>` and cast it to a `List<Animal>`. Now you could `.Add()` a `Sheep` to your `List<Animal>`. But wait... now your `List<Wolf>` contains a `Sheep`. What a mess.

This would only work out if you could make sure that the thing you cast to is read-only in all possible forms. This is was [co- and contravariance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx) is all about. It only works for interfaces though.

Comment: As an example where covariance would work, consider the interface `IReadOnlyList<out T>`. Here if you have an `IReadOnlyList<Wolf>` it would convert _implicitly_ to `IReadOnlyList<Animal>`. The `out` signifies covariance (`in` would be contravariance) in this context. It is correct that `class` types cannot be co- and contravariant like this (as of the current version). Co- and contravariance of this type is only supported for `interface` and `delegate` types.

Comment: List of wolfs with sheeps in it, best explanation ever :)

Comment: Sorry, I disagree with the "mess"... You wouldn't have a list of wolves with sheep in it, you'd have a list of _animals_ containing both wolves and sheep. Which seems perfectly reasonable.

Comment: @Basic Casting from a `List<Wolf>` to a `List<Animal>` would not create a new list neither would it change the type of the original variable or instance. That is not what casting does. You still have only one list, originally declared as `List<Wolf>` and it would have a sheep in it.