# Convert EqualityComparer<Child<T>> into EqualityComparer<Parent>

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, casting, iequalitycomparer

I have such hierarchy :

```
public interface INode
{
    //...
}

public interface INode<T> : INode
{
    //...
}

public class Node : INode
{
    //...
}

public class Node<T> : Node, INode<T>
{
    //...     
}
```

Now I want to cast like this :

```
EqualityComparer<INode<int>> intcomparer = EqualityComparer<INode<int>>.Default;
EqualityComparer<INode> comparer = intcomparer;
```

Why this casting is invalid ? and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why should the cast be valid?

What makes you believe that `EqualityComparer<T>` derives from `EqualityComparer<Random base class/interface of T>` or `EqualityComparer<every possible base class/interface of T>`?

You can't compare it to this:

```
Node<string> stringNode;
Node node = stringNode;
```

This works since your class Definition of `Node<T>` explicitly derives from the non-generic version of `Node`

```
public class Node<T> : Node, INode<T>
```

When you have a look at the class definition of 
 [`EqualityComparer<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.equalitycomparer-1)

```
public abstract class EqualityComparer<T> : 
    System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<T>,
    System.Collections.IEqualityComparer
```

You can see there is no non-generic version, you could change your code to his though:

```
EqualityComparer<INode<int>> intcomparer = EqualityComparer<INode<int>>.Default;
IEqualityComparer comparer = intcomparer;
```

But, `IEqualityComparer` will have no information about your `INode` and only define a `Equals(object, object)` method.

This is valid for every generic class, eg. see this related, maybe even duplicate question:

[Cast Generic<Derived> to Generic<Base>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41179199/cast-genericderived-to-genericbase)

**Update:**

After, noticing that `IEqualityComparer<T>` is defined as `IEqualityComparer<in T>` - so contravariant is possible, you can have a look at this:

[Variance in generic Interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/variance-in-generic-interfaces)

The other way around you currently have is possible, with the interfaces `IEqualityComparer<T>` doesn't work on class.

```
IEqualityComparer<INode> comparer = EqualityComparer<INode>.Default;
IEqualityComparer<INode<int>> intcomparer = comparer;
```