# C# Generics covariant

Tags: c#, generics

I ran into an issue with generics which I believed can be solved with covariance, but  don't fully understand how covarience works and how it can be declared properly.
Let's say I have the following interfaces and classes:

```
public interface IOwnedObject<TUser>
where TUser : IBaseUser
{
    string UserId { get; set; }
    TUser User { get; set; }
}

public interface IBaseUser
{
    string Id { get; set; }
}

public class User : IBaseUser
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

public class SomeOwnedObject : IOwnedObject<User>
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

Then consider the following code:

```
var obj = new SomeOwnedObject();
            if(obj is IOwnedObject<IBaseUser> o)
                Console.WriteLine("Success"); // This never executes
```

The above if statement does not evaluate to true. However, in `IOwnedObject` it's only ever possible for `TUser` to be `IBaseUser`.

The following code evaluates to true:

```
var obj = new SomeOwnedObject();
            if(obj is IOwnedObject<User> o)
                Console.WriteLine("Success"); // This executes
```

since `User` implements `IBaseUser`, shouldn't `IOwnedObject<IBaseUser>` technically be a base class of `IOwnedObject<User>`. Is it possible to make that first statement evaluate to true without referencing the concrete implementation `User`?

Comment: c# doesn't have templates. it has generics.

Comment: "shouldn't IOwnedObject<IBaseUser> technically be a base class of IOwnedObject<User>" - Just making sure you've seen - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41179199/cast-genericderived-to-genericbase (or any other https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+generic+base+derived)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the first statement to evaluate to true with a few modifications to your interface. We'll want to mark the `TUser` type as covariant with the `out` keyword, and in doing so we'll have to remove the property setter.

```
public interface IOwnedObject<out TUser> where TUser : IBaseUser
{
    string UserId { get; set; }
    TUser User { get; }
}
```

Now evaluating

```
var obj = new SomeOwnedObject();
if (obj is IOwnedObject<IBaseUser> o)
    Console.WriteLine("Success");
```

will result in "Success" being printed to the console.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning removing the property setter. I couldn't figure out what the errors meant when I added out or in keyworks on the type parameter. Works great!

Comment: @Brad Yep, `get` only for covariant, `set` only for contravariant (`in`), and both for invariant. The keywords being `out` and `in` mark the generic variance, as well as describe how the types can be used. A generic parameter marked `in` could use the `in` type as a method parameter's type, but not as a method's return type. A generic parameter marked `out` could use the type as a method's return type, but not as one of the method's parameters. Since getters and setters are just a sugar for methods that will generated, the rules apply to them as well.

Answer (score 0):

Either do @Jonathon's suggestion or the below. Making it covariant you need to use an invariant type, which is IBaseUser.

```
public static void Main()
{
    var obj = new SomeOwnedObject();
        if(obj is IOwnedObject<IBaseUser> o)
            Console.WriteLine("Success"); // This never executes
}

public interface IOwnedObject<out TUser> where TUser : IBaseUser
{
    string UserId { get; set; }
    IBaseUser User { get; set; }
}

public interface IBaseUser
{
    string Id { get; set; }
}

public class User : IBaseUser
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

public class SomeOwnedObject : IOwnedObject<User>
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public IBaseUser User { get; set; }
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/PAE3CW

Comment: This removes the generic type parameter from being used entirely, since the parameter isn't utilized. It ends up being a constraint on declaration, but doesn't restrict the property type to the provided type as is likely intended.