# Multiple constructors using generics and lists

Tags: c#, generics, constructor

Is there a simple way to have a class with two constructors such as:

```
public MyClass
{
  public MyClass(object obj)
  {
  }

  public MyClass(List<object> obj)
  {
  }
}
```

Where instantiating `MyClass` by passing in a `List<int>` parameter will cause the `List<object>` constructor to be used?

It seems this correctly uses the `List<object>` constructor:

```
List<object> l = new List<object>();
l.Add(10);
l.Add(20);
MyClass c = new MyClass(l);
```

But this goes to the `object` constructor instead of the `List<object>` constructor:

```
MyClass c = new MyClass(new List<int> { 10, 20 });
```

Any idea how to correct this?  I'd like to use the `List<object>` constructor if any `List<>` is passed in.

Thanks!

Comment: c# != Java... So you can't . You may indeed use generics, but that not what you are asking... (background reading - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41179199/cast-genericderived-to-genericbase)

Comment: Why does your object need to represent both a single object and a list of object?  Just have it represent a list of objects that may happen to contain exactly one item in it.

Comment: Your problem is that `List<int>` has no conversion to `List<object>` and you can't have a generic constructor. You can, however, have a `static` factory method that is generic.

Comment: That answer that Alexei linked to is really the answer to this. A `List<int>` cannot be casted to `List<object>` because that would allow you add anything to your list. e.g. `obj.Add("somestring")` would work.

Comment: A bowl of apples is something that I can only add apples to. If I could cast it to a bowl of fruit then I could add bananas. But you can't add bananas to a bowl of apples. Likewise you can't cast a `List<int>` to a `List<object>`.

Comment: Thanks all, seems a static factory may be the way to go.