# Accessing property of derived type in a class derived from a generic class

Tags: c#, generics, derived-class

I'm still new to C# and cannot wrap my head around this issue.

I have a two classes deriving from a generic class with T deriving from BackgroundWorker (see below). How can I have a field in another class that is able to hold either of the two derived classes and access the field with the derived BackgroundWorker? I need to be able to subscribe to the derived BackgroundWorker's events and issue e.g. CancelAsync command...

I have a generic class:

```
public class GenericClass<T> where T : BackgroundWorker
    {
        public T BgWorker;
    }
```

and derive two classes from it:

```
public class DerivedOne : GenericClass<BackgroundWorkerOne>
    { }

public class DerivedTwo : GenericClass<BackgroundWorkerTwo>
    { }
```

where:

```
public class BackgroundWorkerOne : BackgroundWorker
    { }

public class BackgroundWorkerOne : BackgroundWorker
    { }
```

However, how can I make a field/property in another class that is able to hold either DerivedOne or DerivedTwo depending on some other variable?

I have tried

```
public class AnotherClass
{
   public GenericClass<BackgroundWorker> Derived;

   public void DoSomething()
   {
      Derived = new DerivedOne();
   }
}
```

But I get the "Cannot implicitly convert type 'DerivedOne' to 'GenericClass<BackgroundWorker>'" error. Casting it

```
Derived = (GenericClass<BackgroundWorker>)new DerivedOne();
```

does not work either.

As mentioned, I would like to subscribe to the events in `Derived.BgWorker` regardless if the `Derived` is of type `DerivedOne` or `DerivedTwo`.

Is using generics here the best option? Or would another path (interface, shadowing or something else entirely) be a better solution?

Any help would be appreciated!

**EDIT**

I see that my approach, as has been pointed out in [Cast Generic<Derived> to Generic<Base>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41179199/cast-genericderived-to-genericbase), is not really feasible. Thank you for that clarification. The code I've shown above is only what I have tried so far, not necesarrily a fixed direction in which the code has to develop.

Furthermore, my question was more geared towards finding a way to access the BackgroundWorker (property with varying types in different classes) from the same base class.

What would be a suitable alternative to be able to access the BackgroundWorker (wheather `BackroundWorkerOne` or `BackgroundWorkerTwo`) property of the `Derived` property? Is there a possiblity to do so or should I rethink my concept?

Comment: when you alrteady know that `AnotherClass` depends on `DerivedOne`. why not just make the property of that specific type? Anyway you should learn about [covariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/). In Short only because two types have some inheritance doen't mean that generics also have. A `List<Derived>` simply is not a `List<Base>`, or in your case a `DerivedOne` is *not* a `GenericClass<BackgroundWorker>`, but a `GeneroicClass<BackgroundWorkerOne>`.

Comment: Because it can depend on `DerivedTwo` just as well, depending on where in the process the whole program is. I want to have a "unified" property that always has access to the BackgroundWorker currently running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [covariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/) is what is missing in your code ?
You can have this interface

```
public interface IGenericClass<out T> where T : BackgroundWorker
{
    T BackgroundWorker { get; }
}
```

Then you can use this interface like this

```
public class AnotherClass
{
   public IGenericClass<BackgroundWorker> Derived;

   public void DoSomething()
   {
      Derived = new DerivedOne();
   }
}

public class DerivedOne : IGenericClass<BackgroundWorkerOne>
{
    public BackgroundWorkerOne BackgroundWorker { get; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this compiles. However, I still don't know how to access the BackgroundWorker in `DerivedOne` or `DerivedTwo` as it is not a property (If I try to declare it as a property in the interface, I get the Invalid variance error (The type parameter 'T' must be invariantly valid on 'IGenericClass<T>.BgWorker. 'T' is covariant.)
Any suggestions to how to solve this?

Comment: @stevan here you go

Comment: @stevan1986, you just need to not have a setter in your interface